# Compose various bower sources together, using Gulp

Tags: bower, gulp

for my projects, I will use different packages from different sources, mostly for PHP use, but these packages will bring their own JavaScript along.

These different packages will all have their own bower definitions and I'd like to compose them all together (if necessary, also "hard coded").

What would be the best way to do that via Gulp?

Thanks and best!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use [`main-bower-files`](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) which will find your bower files and glob them into one source.

```
bower = require('main-bower-files');

gulp.task('task_name', [], function() {
    return gulp.src(bower())
        .pipe(/* ... */)
        /* ... */
});
```